# conditionally delete values in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have this dataframe:

```
df <-data.frame(x1=c("ball", "chair", "potato", "juice", "pen"), x2=c("phone", "blue", "paper", "sun", "color"))
```

how can I delete all the values that contain the letter "c"?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! What have you tried so far? What should be the result?

Comment: Try `df[sapply(df, function(i)grepl('c', i))] <- NA`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to "delete" only the individual cells

```
data.frame(
  sapply(df,function(x){
    ifelse(grepl("c",x),NA,x)
  })
)
      x1    x2
1   ball phone
2   <NA>  blue
3 potato paper
4   <NA>   sun
5    pen  <NA>
```

**Edit:** Sotos' version posted in the comments is more efficient, which achieves the same result.

```
df[sapply(df, function(i)grepl('c', i))] <- NA
```

Comment: You don't need `grepl(...) == TRUE`. By default `grepl` will return TRUE or FALSE. Also no need for ifelse and restructuring to data frame. Check my comment

Comment: @Sotos Yes I saw, your version is better.

Comment: I am not posting an answer anyway so feel free to edit my version in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove rows when one `"c"` occur in any of the columns you can do :

```
df[rowSums(sapply(df, grepl, pattern = 'c')) == 0, ]

#      x1    x2
#1   ball phone
#3 potato paper
```

In `dplyr`, you can use `filter_all` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter_all(all_vars(!grepl('c', .)))
```

---

To change the values to `NA` you can use :

```
df %>%  mutate_all(~replace(., grepl('c', .), NA))

#      x1    x2
#1   ball phone
#2   <NA>  blue
#3 potato paper
#4   <NA>   sun
#5    pen  <NA>
```

Comment: I need only to clean up the single cells where there is the letter c, keeping then the same number of rows. I would get this way some empty cells.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the newly released dplyr adverb 'across' if you like to work in the tidyverse:

```html
# using dplyr 1.0.0+

library(dplyr)

na_if_c <- function (x) {
  replace <- x[grepl("c", x)]
  na_if(x, replace)
}

df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), na_if_c))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   filter(!rowSums(across(everything(), ~ str_detect(., 'c'))))
#      x1    x2
#1   ball phone
#2 potato paper
```